# How to associate Price with Different item in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am newbie in unity. i am facing a small Problem. I have a different number of items and i want to  associate Different Price with them . 
but i dont know  **How to access Text(script) component in Unity?** ?????

Lets says Here is the ***book shop every book Container Have different price***

[image]

**Here what i try to do but i don't know how to access this** **text Using Script** 
[image]

Thanks in  advance

[image]

[image: Here objprice is all these toys and these are child objects of Book Name and Book name is the very first toy bear]

Comment: Create an own script where your have an decimal property to save the price. In the setter (or Update) you set the Text (get it with the GetComponent method)

Comment: How will the price need to be accessed? Do you go to a shopkeeper who has a list of books or must you go over and select each book from the shelf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the *"NumericalScore*" GameObject with `GameObject.Find` then get the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component from it with the `GetComponent` function.

```
//Find the Text GameObject
GameObject textObj = GameObject.Find("NumericalScore");

//Get the Text component
Text text = textObj.GetComponent<Text>();
string bookText = text.text;
```

Now, let's say that the each book has different names but with a Child text with **the-same name** called *"NumericalScore"*, find the book name first then use `transform.Find` to find the child Text GameObject before using the `GetComponent` function to get the `Text` component.

```
//Find Book
GameObject book = GameObject.Find("BookName");

//Find Child Text GameObject
GameObject textObj = book.transform.Find("NumericalScore").gameObject;

//Get the Text component
Text text = textObj.GetComponent<Text>();
string bookText = text.text;
```

Comment: With second approach  it just take price of very first object

Comment: GameObject.Find should be avoided usually as it's not very performance friendly.

I'd advise that he instead has some way of finding each individual book, either by raycasting when he looks at the book or by storing the books in an array he can go through, which only contains the books.

Comment: @Ahmad I expect your book hierarchy to be like this: BookName -> NumericalScore for each book. Upload a screenshot that shows what the Hierarchy of each book look like. Seriously though, read the answer then tailor `GameObject.Find` and `GetComponent`  to however you arranged the hierarchy. This is not complicated at-all.

Comment: @Doh09 I don't know what raycast has to do with this. It is irrelevant.  OP wants to access the `Text` component from each book as bolded in the question. There is nothing wrong with `GameObject.Find`. To find a particular Object/book, `GameObject.Find` is used to do that. `GameObject.Find` is only bad when used in an Update function or called every frame. My answer did not do that. It simply shows how to find an Object/book and then retrieving the `Text` component from it with `GetComponent`. OP can cache the items returned by both of these functions.

Comment: @Programmer I just  Edit and upload object hierarchy In My Original  Question Please Have a look 
waiting for you response  Thanks A lot

Comment: Raycasting would allow him to access a single object instead of having the script cycle through all the objects of the scene. For example if he points at the book and accesses the Gameobject reference via Raycasting, then he only has a single object to work with.

As for GameObject.Find, not everyone is fond of it.

https://akbiggs.silvrback.com/please-stop-using-gameobject-find

Arguably he would be better off making a script that holds a list of all the books, for example by adding each book to the list on Awake, and then accessing that script to go through the books.

Comment: @Ahmad What is the Objprice? Is it the object with the `Text` or is it the book?

Comment: It is Book  @Programmer

Comment: @Doh09 Please stop. The article you linked didn't say anything about using raycast. You have over 50 items in the scene and you just want to reference them, you have to use a raycast? That's the craziest thing I have ever read this year. That article is only saying you should use a public variable but what if you have many objects and different types of objects and is dynamically created? You don't have to answer this but please stop with the raycast advice. I don't think you understand whay raycast is used for.

Comment: @Ahmad but then where is the "NumericalScore" object with the Text you want to access? I mean what is the Objprice? An Object with the book mesh or an object a Text component? That screesnot is different from your "NumericalScore"  screenshot. It would be helpful to explain what is object is. You are not making this easy to answer.

Comment: The article I linked was concerning some of the issues related to using GameObject.Find, not anything with the raycasting. He may only have 50 items now, but we don't know what his future plans are, he might later have a lot more objects. The Raycasting was just a suggestion in case he needed to be able to pick a book from a shelf. It appears to me you misread what I mean, raycasting can be used to interact with objects in the game world to get a hold of them, I have used it many times...

As for what I mean with the publist list the items could be added to: https://pastebin.com/Yz35kc6E

Comment: @Programmer i make it quiet easy for you upload orignal picture of my game along 

Here obj price are the toys (all toys have same name as you just said )
and Booknmae is the name of first Toy

Comment: Ok but then what's attached to each "objprice"?  A text component? You have never posted the inspector screenshot of that. Is the "NumericalScore" object still there? Did you delete it? If so, mention that and remove that screenshot from your question too.

Comment: @Programmer Oh sorry i forget to inform i just replace NumericalScore with objprice

Comment: `GameObject book = GameObject.Find("BookName");` to find the "BookName" then `Text[] texts = book.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();` to access all the children texts from all the `objprice` as array. Let me know if there is an issue with that

Comment: Ok ThanKs A lot I will surely Share With You

Comment: Yes its Work ! But can You tell we 1 more thing Please how can i find  Index of exact toy on which it click 

I try something like 

GameObject book = GameObject.Find("BookName");
  Text[] texts = book.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
  Debug.Log (texts [2].text);

it give 170 because i hard code its index but finally it start give some result  Thankss  @Programmer

Comment: As it hold all value but how can we access the index of that object on which we click Your effort is Much appreciated  thanks

Comment: This means you will first have to detect click on the text. Do you want to detect which Text(objprice) is clicked?

Comment: Yes ! @Programmer Only then i will achieve my desire Result

Comment: See [this](https://pastebin.com/aWvANkGa) for complete example. The `textToIndex` function is very easy to understand if you read the comments. Attach that script to the `BookName` object which is the parent. Also make sure that Event System is in your scene GameObject-->UI-->Event System. Also since this is a Text, the `BookName` object must also be under a Canvas. That should work.

Comment: Thanks A lot @Programmer  
Highly appreciated  Thanks Again

Comment: You are welcome. I know you are new to this site and you don't know the rules. Only upvote the answer. Don't go and upvote my other answers. In most cases, it is called [Serial Upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and the votes will be reversed the next day. Upvoting 1 or 2 answers from the-same person is ok but not so many like 4 and above. Glad I was able to help and happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer Oh i was pretty unaware of that I will be care full for next time
Thank & Can you help us in very small thing Really need your guide line Thanks in advance , And my game is almost completed :)
Here is my question   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495065/unity-ads-and-ad-mob-ads-integration-with-heyzap-is-not-working-completely